# PDO dblib get result from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, pdo

I have a problem to get result from stored procedure on MSSQL server 2012. Using PHP 5.4.34, dblib, CentOS. On my dev where I use sqlsrv extension for PHP everything works OK.

PDO INIT:

```
 $this->pdo = new PDO('dblib:host=88.88.88.88;dbname=dbName', $connection['login'], $connection['pass'] );
```

And call the procedure:

```
     $sqlStr = "DECLARE @price decimal(15, 4), @resutl tinyint, @err_message varchar(1000), @act_list char(16), @act_list_poradi smallint;
                 EXEC [dba].[get_price] @arg_id_cust = ?, @arg_cislo_nomenklatury = ?, @arg_mnozstvi = ?,@arg_id_mj = ?, @typ_param = ?,@price = @price OUTPUT,@resutl = @resutl OUTPUT, @err_message = @err_message OUTPUT, @act_list = @act_list OUTPUT, @act_list_poradi = @act_list_poradi OUTPUT;
                 SELECT @price as cena";
 $sth = $this->kPDO->prepare($sqlStr);
 if ($sth){
                $sth->bindParam(1, $idCust);
                $sth->bindParam(2, $idNomen);
                $sth->bindParam(3, $ks);
                $sth->bindParam(4, $mj);
                $sth->bindParam(5, $param);
                $res = $sth->execute();
 }else{
                throw new Exception('Chybny statement');
            }
```

$res is true, but $sth->fetch() return FALSE and no error is ommited.

Thank for any help.

Comment: Hi did you find a solution for this? I am on the similar boat.